# Sql: difference between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, difference

one short question:

I am using this code

```
SELECT trunc (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE('04/10/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') Differenz FROM DUAL;
```

to calculate the differnece between two dates.

I would like to add that it ignores Saturdays, Sundays and holidays (not school holidays I mean holidays like christmas, eastern..). My local time zone is Germany (each country has its own holidays).

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the name of your calendar table that describes holidays and weekend days for each country?

Comment: "holidays" is pretty much a useless term. everyone has a different definition of what is a holiday, and then there's holidays which shift around, like labor day and easter. you're not going to find a single function which handles that for you.

Comment: its Gregorian calendar!

Comment: I mean official holidays set by state

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331951/calculate-diffference-between-2-dates-in-sql-excluding-weekend-days - it's a start at least ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with 1 level deep nesting limit in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429631/how-to-deal-with-1-level-deep-nesting-limit-in-oracle)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429631/how-to-deal-with-1-level-deep-nesting-limit-in-oracle/29430140#29430140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the number of days exclude Saturday and Sunday is not so difficult, you will find several solutions for that at SO.

Considering holidays is more challenging. One solution is be to use the Oracle `SCHEDULER`.  By default this is used for `SCHEDULER JOBS`, however I don't see any reason not using it for other purpose.

Biggest problem is the easter day, see here: [Computus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus).
I think the most efficient way is to hard-code the dates and maintaine them manually.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('New_Year', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0101');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Easter_Sunday',  repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405,    20160327,    20170416,    20170416,    20180401,    20190421,    20200412', comments => 'Hard coded till 2020');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Good_Friday',    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405-2D, 20160327-2D, 20170416-2D, 20170416-2D, 20180401-2D, 20190421-2D, 20200412-2D');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Easter_Monday',   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405+1D, 20160327+1D, 20170416+1D, 20170416+1D, 20180401+1D, 20190421+1D, 20200412+1D');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Ascension_Day',   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405+39D,20160327+39D,20170416+39D,20170416+39D,20180401+39D,20190421+39D,20200412+39D');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Pentecost_Monday', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405+50D,20160327+50D,20170416+50D,20170416+50D,20180401+50D,20190421+50D,20200412+50D');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Repentance_and_Prayer', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDATE=1122-SPAN:7D;BYDAY=WED', 
        comments => 'Wednesday before November 23th, Buss- und Bettag');
    -- alternative solution: 
    --DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Repentance_and_Prayer', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=NOV;BYDAY=3 WED', 
    --    comments => '3rd Wednesday in November');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Labor_Day', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0501');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('German_Unity_Day', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=1003');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Christmas', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=1225+SPAN:2D');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Christian_Celebration_Days', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERSECT=Easter_Sunday,Good_Friday,Easter_Monday,Ascension_Day,Pentecost_Monday,Repentance_and_Prayer,Christmas');
    -- alternative solution: 
    -- DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Christian_Celebration_Days', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=Good_Friday;BYDAY=1 MON, 6 THU,8 MON');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Political_Holidays', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERSECT=New_Year,Labor_Day,German_Unity_Day');


END;
/
```

See syntax for calendar here: [Calendaring Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF)

Then you can use the schedules like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DateDiff(end_date IN TIMESTAMP) RETURN INTEGER AS
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP := TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP);
    res INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    IF end_date > SYSTIMESTAMP THEN
        LOOP
            DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; EXCLUDE=Christian_Celebration_Days,Political_Holidays', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
            EXIT WHEN next_run_date >= end_date;
            res := res + 1;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN res;
    ELSE
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;     
END;

SELECT DateDiff(TO_DATE('04/10/2015','mm/dd/yyyy')) AS Differenz FROM DUAL;
```

Output next 20 holiays for testing:

```
DECLARE
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..20 LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=DAILY;INTERSECT='Christian_Celebration_Days,Political_Holidays', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(next_run_date);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**Update**

I even found a more compact version:

```
BEGIN
    -- Start with first celebration day (good Friday), all dependent celebration days have to be after this day for proper calculation of schedule
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('GOOD_FRIDAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20100402,20110422,20120406,20130329,20140418,20150403,20160325,20170414,20180330,20190419,20200410,20210402,20220410,20230407,20240329,20250418,20260403,20270326,20280414,20290330,20300419', comments => 'Hard coded 2010 to 2030');
    -- Easter Sunday can be skipped for list of holidays, otherwise 'FREQ=Good_Friday;BYDAY=1 SUN+SPAN:2D'
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('EASTER_MONDAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=Good_Friday;BYDAY=1 MON', comments => '1st Monday after Good Friday'
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('ASCENSION_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=Good_Friday;BYDAY=6 THU', comments => '6th Thursday after Good Friday (40 days after Easter)');
    -- Pentecost Sunday can be skipped for list of holidays, otherwise 'FREQ=Good_Friday;BYDAY=8 SUN+SPAN:2D'
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('PENTECOST_MONDAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=Good_Friday;BYDAY=8 MON', comments => '8th Monday after Good Friday (50 days after Easter)');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('EASTER_RELATED_DAYS', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=Good_Friday;BYDAY=1 MON, 6 THU,8 MON'
END;
```